# Rails: Can you impose multiple sort orders, in the same line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For instance:

```
@examples = @user.examples.mostrecent.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Where "mostrecent" is defined as:

```
def self.mostrecent
  self.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

So basically the first call to the database is pull every User's example, and then on top of that, order them by most recent first. It seems like this should be doable, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

There is no defined order scope in the model I'm working with, and other calls to order work just fine. By checking the development.log I can see only the first database pulling example by users is respected. The mostrecent order is never called.

Is there a Rails way of doing this all in one line?

Comment: Why don't you make that a scope?

Comment: Also, I see only one sort, but question title mentioned multiple sort orders. What's up with that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the call to pull all of the examples from Users, was.....a sort of sorts.

Comment: And can't make a scope, as in other places I need to use a different order (by highest voted) which gets overridden by the default scope

Comment: make it a scope, not a default scope. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scope, as in:

```
scope :by_recent, lambda 
  { |since_when| order("created_at") }
```

Comment: I'm trying to keep away from default scopes, in other places I need to use a different order (by highest voted) which gets overridden by the default scope

Comment: This is a named scope though, not a default.

Comment: You don't use the labmda parameter.

Comment: Ahhhh okay. That really highlights my ignorance lol. I thought all scopes acted as default. This solves it.